# Array of strings from the most common function

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to call each string from an array. However, I am using this code to generate the array.

```
function extract_common_words($string, $stop_words, $max_count = 5) {
    $string = preg_replace('/ss+/i', '', $string);
    $string = trim($string); // trim the string
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z -]/', '', $string); // Only take alphabet characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
    $string = strtolower($string); // Make it lowercase

    preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $match_words);
    $match_words = $match_words[0];

    foreach ( $match_words as $key => $item ) {
        if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stop_words) || strlen($item) <= 3    ) {
            unset($match_words[$key]);
        }
    }

    $word_count = str_word_count( implode(" ", $match_words) , 1);
    $frequency = array_count_values($word_count);
    arsort($frequency);

    //arsort($word_count_arr);
    $keywords = array_slice($frequency,0);
    return $keywords;
}
```

It returns an array which I can't seem to get the STRINGS from. So, I want to essentially take the results, and place them in a list which is an array of strings, with each string being the words, in consecutive order from most common to least common.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strtok function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php). Or else you can explode the string by whitespace. I hope that helps :)

Comment: Had a look but not sure how to implement it. This is how my array looks when I call the print_ r function;

Array ( [ladygaga] => 2 [marcus] => 1 [brigstocke] => 1 [georgejeie] => 1 [george] => 1 [dbeckham] => 1 [becks] => 1 ) 1

and this is the input array:

$keywords = extract_common_words("ladygaga ladygaga dbeckham becks george george" . "Jessie J Marcus Brigstocke");

any ideas?